# Integral of exponential and algebraic function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I would like to know, if it exists, a closed form for:

$$\int_0^{+\infty}\,\frac{k}{ak^4+bk^2+c}\,\,\exp(-wk^2)\,\,dk$$

with $a,b,c,w>0$.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternate approach, you may simply express in terms of a Laplace transform; to pick up where @Harry Peter left off:

$$I(w)=\int_0^{\infty} dk \, k \frac{e^{-w k^2}}{a k^4+b k^2+c}  = \frac12 \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{-w x}}{a x^2+b x+c}$$

Let the roots of the denominator of the integrand be $x_+$ and $x_-$.  Then

$$I(w) = \frac{1}{2 a} \frac{1}{x_+-x_-} \left [\int_0^{\infty}dx \frac{e^{-w x}}{x-x_+} - \int_0^{\infty}dx \frac{e^{-w x}}{x-x_-} \right ]$$

if these integrals exist. Now,

$$x_{\pm} = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4 a c}}{2 a}$$

and because $a$, $b$, and $c$ are all positive, then the roots $x_{\pm}$ are either negative or complex, so the integrals will exist.  If, however, the roots are equal, a slightly different approach will be required.

Each of these integrals maybe expressed in terms of either an incomplete gamma function, or as Harry notes, an exponential integral:

$$I(w) = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{b^2-4 a c}} \left [e^{w x_+} E_1\left (-w x_+\right) - e^{w x_-} E_1\left (-w x_-\right)  \right ]$$

For real, distinct, negative roots, the above expression is no problem.  For complex roots ($b^2-4 a c \lt 0$), however, care must be taken to respect the branch cut along the negative real axis that is part of the definition of $E_1$.

For double roots ($b^2-4 a c=0$), we recognize that

$$I(w) = \frac{1}{a} \int_0^{\infty}dx \frac{e^{-w x}}{(x-x_+)^2} $$

where $x_+ = -b/(2 a) \lt 0$.  In this case, we use a [generalized exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Relation_with_other_functions), again, related to the incomplete gamma function, and is

$$I(w) = \frac{e^{w x_+}}{a} E_2(-w x_+)$$

Comment: Thanks. Anyway there is a minus missing in the exponential prefactor ($\exp(-\omega x_{\pm})$).

Answer (score 1):

You can evaluate the integral by using partial fraction and the following identity

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-wx^2}}{\alpha x+\beta}dx= \frac{1}{2\pi \beta \sqrt{w} }\,
> G^{3, 2}_{2, 3}\left({\frac {{\beta}^{2}w}{{\alpha}^{2}}}\, \Big\vert\,^{\frac{1}{2}, 1}_{1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}}\right),$$

where $G^{3, 2}_{2, 3}$ is the [Meijer G-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function).

Comment: Ok thanks. But how could I go from $\frac{k}{ak^4+bk^2+c}$ to $\frac{1}{\alpha x+\beta}$?

Comment: @JFNJr: Just use [partial fraction techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition). You need to factor the polynomial $ak^4+bk^2+c$ to linear factors. This can be done by finding the roots of the polynomial and the n use the partial fraction techniques. Note that, $ak^4+bk^2+c=(k-r_1)(k-r_2)(k-r_3)(k-r_4)$, where $r_i$ are the roots of the polynomial.

Comment: @Downvoter: I hope there is a reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

$\int_0^\infty\dfrac{ke^{-wk^2}}{ak^4+bk^2+c}dk$

$=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\dfrac{e^{-wk^2}}{ak^4+bk^2+c}d(k^2)$

$=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\dfrac{e^{-wk}}{ak^2+bk+c}dk$

Case $1$: $b^2-4ac\neq0$

Then $\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\dfrac{e^{-wk}}{ak^2+bk+c}dk$

$=\dfrac{1}{2a}\int_0^\infty\dfrac{e^{-wk}}{\left(k+\dfrac{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right)\left(k+\dfrac{b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right)}dk$

$=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}\int_0^\infty\dfrac{e^{-wk}}{k+\dfrac{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}}dk-\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}\int_0^\infty\dfrac{e^{-wk}}{k+\dfrac{b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}}dk$

$=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}\int_\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}^\infty\dfrac{e^{-w\bigl(k-\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\bigr)}}{k}d\biggl(k-\dfrac{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\biggr)-\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}\int_\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}^\infty\dfrac{e^{-w\bigl(k-\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\bigr)}}{k}d\biggl(k-\dfrac{b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\biggr)$

$=\dfrac{e^{\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}w}}{2\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}\int_\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}^\infty\dfrac{e^{-wk}}{k}dk-\dfrac{e^{\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}w}}{2\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}\int_\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}^\infty\dfrac{e^{-wk}}{k}dk$

$=\dfrac{e^{\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}w}}{2\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}\int_1^\infty\dfrac{e^{-w\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}k}}{\dfrac{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}k}d\left(\dfrac{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}k\right)-\dfrac{e^{\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}w}}{2\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}\int_1^\infty\dfrac{e^{-w\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}k}}{\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}k}d\left(\dfrac{b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}k\right)$

$=\dfrac{e^{\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}w}}{2\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}\int_1^\infty\dfrac{e^{-\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}wk}}{k}dk-\dfrac{e^{\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}w}}{2\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}\int_1^\infty\dfrac{e^{-\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}wk}}{k}dk$

$=\dfrac{e^{\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}w}}{2\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}E_1\biggl(\dfrac{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}w\biggr)-\dfrac{e^{\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}w}}{2\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}E_1\biggl(\dfrac{b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}w\biggr)$

Case $2$: $b^2-4ac=0$

Then $\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\dfrac{e^{-wk}}{ak^2+bk+c}dk$

$=\dfrac{1}{2a}\int_0^\infty\dfrac{e^{-wk}}{\left(k+\dfrac{b}{2a}\right)^2}dk$

$=\dfrac{1}{2a}\int_\frac{b}{2a}^\infty\dfrac{e^{-w\left(k-\frac{b}{2a}\right)}}{k^2}d\left(k-\dfrac{b}{2a}\right)$

$=\dfrac{e^{\frac{bw}{2a}}}{2a}\int_\frac{b}{2a}^\infty\dfrac{e^{-wk}}{k^2}dk$

$=\dfrac{e^{\frac{bw}{2a}}}{2a}\int_1^\infty\dfrac{e^{-\frac{bkw}{2a}}}{\left(\dfrac{bk}{2a}\right)^2}d\left(\dfrac{bk}{2a}\right)$

$=\dfrac{e^{\frac{bw}{2a}}}{b}\int_1^\infty\dfrac{e^{-\frac{bwk}{2a}}}{k^2}dk$

$=\dfrac{e^{\frac{bw}{2a}}}{b}E_2\left(\dfrac{bw}{2a}\right)$